# See What Is Linking to An URL

Tags: hyperlink

I have an URL that I need to change, but I have no clue what is linking to it. Is there an online tool that can scan such behavior?

Comment: Keep the old URL as a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google search for `link:your-url.com/your-page`.

Of course this will only show pages that are in Google's index. Other search engines have similar capabilities but I can't recall the syntax offhand.